# Bridge jQuery UI droppable to Lift ajax handler

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, scala, lift

I'm working on a web application project using Scala / Lift. I would like to make my application support drag and drop to improve the user experience.

But I'm not quite sure how to bridge jQuery part with Lift.

Currently I've a working UI part, an div block has class named `listRow` is dragable with an HTML5 attribute `data-stuffid` which has an ID from database.

It can be dragged to an block named `nextAction`, and I could print out the `data-stuffid` field correctly in JavaScript.

Here is my JavaScript code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.listRow').draggable({
      revert: true
  });

$("#nextAction").droppable({
    accept: ".listRow",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    activeClass: "dropActive",
    hoverClass: "dropHover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var stuffID = ui.draggable.data("stuffid")
        console.log(stuffID)
    }
})
```

But I don't know how to call to a Lift AJAX handler, and pass stuffID to Lift in the case.

What I would like to do is have an Scala function likes the following:

```
def showDialog(stuffID: String): JsCmds
{
    // Do some server side work, ex: querying database

    // Return a javascript cmds likes SHtml.ajaxButton...etc.
    Alert("SutffID:" + stuffID)
}
```

And when user drag a `.listRow` to "#nextAction", `showDialog` would be called, and return the javascript to browser and let browser execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably looking for one of these two functions. I'd take a look at :

[`JsCmds.Function`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmds%24%24Function%24.html) and [`SHtml.ajaxCall`](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.0/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/SHtml%24object.html)

`JsCmds.Function` will allow you to create a JavaScript function, and `SHtml.ajaxCall` will allow you to execute code via ajax. You'd create a function in your Lift CSS Selector and then you'd be able to call that functions directly from your jQuery code.

There are a lot of discussions on using both those, some relevant info might be:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/4EyE1EbcDDM
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/aAmvSjPxcyI

Answer (score 0):

When initializing jquery from lift, just send lift ajax callback as parameter

Comment: @dmitry-baskakov Does this mean I need generate the jQuery code I posted in a Lift snippet? I would prefer make it in the templates directly, because it is a fronted-end part, and has nothing to do with business logic.